# Integral and series interchange on $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-x}(1-e^{-ax})}{x}\, dx}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

With $|a|<1$ $$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-x}(1-e^{-ax})}{x}\, dx}\,&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-a)^nx^{n-1}}{n!}}}dx\\&\overset{?}{=}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-a)^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}x^{n-1}\, dx}}\end{align}$$

$e^{-x}$ doesn't dominate $e^{-ax}$ in this case? I know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-a)^n}{n!}}$ converges but I'm not sure how to bound the remaining part for uniform convergence (for example)

Comment: The last integral is $(n-1)!$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_integral)). You will obtain the Maclaurin series of $\log(1+a)$. See also [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral).

Comment: Yes, the convergence issues here are that of the "Frullani integral"... eminently Wiki-able...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx=\Gamma(n) =(n-1)!, $$ so $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-a)^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-a)^n}{n}.$$ Since $|a|<1$, then $a^n\to 0$, so $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-a)^n}{n}<\infty.$$ Also this is sn example of Frullani integralintegral, i.e. the integrals of the form $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(bx) -f(ax)}{x}dx, $$ whose are equal to $$\left(f(\infty)-f(0)\right) \log(b/a), $$ where $f(\infty)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$. In our case $f(x)=e^{-x}$, $b=1$ and $a=a+1 $. Since $e^{-x}\to 0$, then the integral is equal to $$-\log \frac{1}{a+1}=\log (a+1). $$

Comment: Last series starts from $n=0$.